# get data from database to write Json format In Scala

Tags: mysql, scala, rest, playframework

Help me, I'm want to query the data from database and save it as json format , then the response  to the client.

```
implicit val locationWrites1: Writes[Location] = (
  (JsPath \ "id").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "desc").write[String]
  ) (unlift(Location.unapply))
db.withConnection { conn =>
  val stm = conn.createStatement()
  val res = stm.executeQuery(
    """
       SELECT notes_id,notes_desc FROM notes
    """
  )
  while (res.next()) {
    Location(res.getString(1), (res.getString(2)))
  }
}
val result = Json.toJson(locationWrites1)

Ok(result)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRkx0.png)

Comment: where is the problem?

Comment: I can't retrieve the data from the query. Save it in json format and send it to the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should hold the locations in a variable first. this code just read the data from DB and don't store it anywhere:

```
while (res.next()) {
 Location(res.getString(1), (res.getString(2)))
}
```

you have to hold the result, like this:

```
val locationsList = mutable.ListBuffer[Location]()
while (res.next()) {
 locationsList.append(Location(res.getString(1), (res.getString(2))))
}
```

then create a Sequence format, like this:

```
 val locationSeqWrites = Writes.seq(locationWrites1)
```

then convert the list to json string:

```
val jsonResponse = locationSeqWrites.writes(locationsList).toString
```

Comment: locationsList.append is not working, it message error  is "cannot resolve symbol append"

Comment: I edited the answer. it should be mutable.ListBuffer[Location]()

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me.^_^

Comment: Do you have  resources to learn more? I'm interested in this and want to learn more.